# Manage Stock - Can't Add Stock after migration

Tags: magento2, migration

When I go to Stores->Stocks there is an error message:

**The website with code base that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.**

I verified that the table inventory_stock is located in the database and contain the Default Stock which no longer shows up in the admin.

This causes a problem where all products are out of stock. When I try to Add New Stock under Manage Stock Magento says it was added, but no new stock appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue after migrating from magento 1.9 to 2.3.

The error message states that the system expects a website with the code(word) "base", which can't be found.
I assume this entry might be a kind of default value. If you migrate your website and don't have a website configured which uses code "base", you'll run into this behavior.

You can fix this by removing the orphaned record directly from database.
Log in to your database search the table *inventory_stock_sales_channel* and remove the entry with *type* = website and *code* = base.

Now the Manage Stock page in the backend should load properly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @bahaspletma

However, first, you need to check the inventory_source table, maybe data in this table has been deleted. If deleted, insert again, here's the query

INSERT INTO `inventory_source` (`source_code`, `name`, `enabled`, `description`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `country_id`, `region_id`, `region`, `city`, `street`, `postcode`, `contact_name`, `email`, `phone`, `fax`, `use_default_carrier_config`) VALUES
('default', 'Default Source',   1,  'Default Source',   0.000000,   0.000000,   'US',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   '00000',    NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   1);